# Error System.IndexOutOfRangeException al tratar de insertar datos

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms

Hola buenas noches a todos,

Estoy recibiendo este error al tratar de insertar los registros mostrados en un dgv y el value member de un ComboBox a SqlServer.

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'An SqlParameter with ParameterName '@DATA_idapp' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection.'

Pero si estoy declarando el parámetro (ComBoBox) en la inserción.

Aquí el código:

```
private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((DGVFile.Rows.Count > 0))
        {
            cnx.Open();
            try
            {
                SqlTransaction transaction;
                transaction = cnx.BeginTransaction();
                try
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ExternalData (LCode,text1,text2,text3,text4,text5,idApplication) values (@DATA_LCode, @DATA_text1, @DATA_text2, @DATA_text3, @DATA_text4, @DATA_text5, @DATA_idapp)", cnx);
                    cmd.Transaction = transaction;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATA_LCode", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATA_text1", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATA_text2", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATA_text3", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATA_text4", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATA_text5", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATA_idapp", SqlDbType.Int);//ValueMember del ComboBox Id

                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DGVFile.Rows)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATA_LCode", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["LCode"].Value));
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATA_text1", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["text1"].Value));
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATA_text2", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["text2"].Value));
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATA_text3", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["text3"].Value));
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATA_text4", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["text4"].Value));
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATA_text5", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["text5"].Value));
                        cmd.Parameters["@DATA_idapp"].Value = cmbSelectApp.SelectedValue;//Agregando el parámetro para insertarlo
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
                catch
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                    throw;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                cnx.Close();
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Records has been saved!", "Succed!!!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not exists data", "Missing Data",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
    }
```

O que es lo que estoy haciendo mal, para insertar los datos mostrados en el dgv y el Id del combobox?

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la primera línea del `foreach` estás eliminando todos los parámetros al llamar a `clear()`. Ver [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.clear?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1).
Luego estás agregando los parámetros de nuevo, junto con su valor. Para todo menos para `@DATA_idapp` que estás tratando de accederlo como si existiera. Pero no existe porque lo borraste con el `clear()`.
Puede que pensaras que `clear()` sólo borraba los valores pero no los parámetros. Supongo que simplemente tenés que quitar esa llamada ya que vas a sobreescribir los valores. Y dejar de usar el `AddWithValue`

```
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DGVFile.Rows)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters["@DATA_LCode"].Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["LCode"].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters["@DATA_text1"].Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["text1"].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters["@DATA_text2"].Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["text2"].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters["@DATA_text3"].Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["text3"].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters["@DATA_text4"].Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["text4"].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters["@DATA_text5"].Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["text5"].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters["@DATA_idapp"].Value = cmbSelectApp.SelectedValue;//Agregando el parámetro para insertarlo
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
```

Comment: Gracias, el error era el que comentas estaba usando incorrectamente el Clear().
Saludos @drkblog